# Restarting ODI 12c load plan persistently goes to the else step of a case step

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

I have a load plan in ODI 12c which goes into error at an 'else' step.
The structure of this problematic part of the plan is:

1. SERIAL step

1.1. RUN SCENARIO for refreshing a variable

1.2. CASE step

- when value = 1 then run scenario X;
- else run dummy scenario to break the load plan.

I fix the issue, restart the plan and expect after the variable is refreshed and its value is 1, to have scenario X run. But it still goes to the else clause. The SERIAL step is with 'Restart all children' option; the dummy scenario in the else is with 'Restart from new session' option. The variable step (1.1) is executed, the variable is refreshed. I also tried all other combinations for restart options for the SERIAL and for the ELSE scenario, but it still 'remembers' the initial path - going directly to the 'else'.
Any suggestions how to reach the scenario X step by restarting the plan? Any hidden setting I'm missing? I read the Oracle documentation all over again but not much help there.

Comment: It looks like a bug to me and I think the best course of action is to open a Service Request on support.oracle.com . As a workaround you can build the same logic within an ODI package.

Comment: JeromeFr, that's a good idea (about the package), only I wanted to make things as simple as possible, but I'll think about it. As for the suggestion for opening a ticket, I was only waiting for the DB admin who has an account there to get back from holidays.. Will do it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

a late comment from my side:
I do not understand, what do you mean by "1.1. RUN SCENARIO for refreshing a variable". Within an ODI loadplan you'll have two options for refreshing a (loadplan) variable and they have to be applied at LP step level:
a) Enable "Overwrite" and enter a literal value OR
b) Enable Refresh
Hope it helps.
Ralf

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).